# Int to datetime or timespan to double

Tags: c#

I need to make a program that reads 4 integer inputs.

```
 int examHour
 int examMin
 int hourArrival
 int minuteArrival
```

Then I have 3 options
Early, if 30 or more minutes earlier.
On time, if the student is on time or 30 min earlier
Late.

I know there is a > < method to do it, but I am 100% sure there is a smarter DateTime or TimeSpan method to do it.

If student is early I have to write
Early {minutes} earlier for less than hour earlier.
HH:mm hours before start for early for a hour or more.
late {minutes} late for less than hour late.
HH:mm hours late for late for a hour or more.

```
namespace OnTime
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int examHour = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int examMin  = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int hourArrival = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int minuteArrival = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            string total = ($"{examHour}:{examMin}");
            string totald = ($"{hourArrival}:{minuteArrival}");


            DateTime arrival = new DateTime();
            arrival = DateTime.ParseExact(total, "H:m", null);
            string resultone = (arrival.ToString("H:mm"));

            DateTime exam = new DateTime();
            exam = DateTime.ParseExact(totald, "H:m", null);
            string resulttwo = (exam.ToString("H:mm"));

            DateTime starttime = Convert.ToDateTime(arrival);
            DateTime arrivaltime = Convert.ToDateTime(exam);

            Console.WriteLine ($"Early {HH:mm} before start")
            Console.WriteLine ($"Late {HH:mm} after start")    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: there’s no reason to use `Convert.ToDateTime` on an object that already is a `DateTime`. Also there’s no reason to parse a string of hours and minutes when you can create an object by giving the hours and minutes in the constructor. But since there’s no date here `Timespan` might be more useful. So first try to do the logic, remove the parts that aren’t needed, and see what happens. Currently you haven’t done the logic yet.

Comment: _but I am 100% sure there is a smarter DateTime or TimeSpan method to do it_,  If you have faith in this, why not tell us the method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you can do your computations and avoid `DateTime` or `TimeSpan` altogether.

```
double exam = examHour + examMin / 60.0;
double arrival = hourArrival + minuteArrival / 60.0;

double delta = exam - arrival;

string status = delta > 0.5 ? "Early" : (delta < 0.0 ? "Late" : "On time");
```

This just creates a `double` with the value being hours with a decimal fraction representing the minutes.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

namespace OnTime
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int examHour = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int examMin  = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int hourArrival = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int minuteArrival = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            string total = ($"{examHour}:{examMin}");
            string totald = ($"{hourArrival}:{minuteArrival}");

            DateTime arrival = new DateTime();
            arrival = DateTime.ParseExact(total, "H:m", null);

            DateTime exam = new DateTime();
            exam = DateTime.ParseExact(totald, "H:m", null);

            TimeSpan span = arrival - exam;
            int hours = span.Hours;
            int minutes = span.Minutes;
            string timediff = hours.ToString("0") + ":" + minutes.ToString("00");
            string minutesdiffOne = minutes.ToString("00");

            if (examHour < hourArrival && (examMin - minuteArrival < 30))
            Console.WriteLine("on time");
            Console.WriteLine($"{minutesdiff:F0}");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are not considered great answers. Please add an explanation of what you did that makes it the solution to the problem.